# Weighting data and show blank cells "0" issue with expss R

Tags: r, statistics, crosstab, expss, cro

I have codes below. It has not an error but when I weight the table with "tab_weight" it just effects inline rows. The total row numbers does not change. Total row numbers needs to change how can I do that?

And the second thing is If there is in cell it shows blank. Is it possible to change to zero "0"? For example row "Erzurum" has no case it should be shown 0 0 0 0 0 ...

```
df %>% 
tab_cells(F1) %>%
tab_cols(tepe_kolonlari) %>% 
tab_weight(sys_RespNum) %>% 
tab_stat_cases(total_label = "Sum", total_row_position = "above") %>% 
tab_pivot()
```

output is

```
            Kadın    Erkek           18 - 24     25 –34      35 - 44     45- 54          A       B       C1      C2      D       E 
 #Toplam    204         122     82      25  81  98          30  76  74  15  6   3
 Ankara     2832        2087    745         339     1174    1319            678     828     1145    87  94  
 Antalya    1203        525     678             525     678                 517     686             
 Bursa      2257        1269    988         1038    899     320                 345     902     340     670     
 Erzurum                                                                
 Gaziantep                                                                  
 İstanbul   30010       18746   11264       2567    11835   15608           2462    11888   13626   1664        370
 İzmir      2601        1476    1125        1416    327     858             364     198     887     333     575     244
 Kayseri    199         199                 199                     199                 
 Malatya    220             220         220                         220                 
 Samsun     1451        979     472             940     511             188     752         511         
 Tekirdağ   225         192     33          192     33              33      192
```

Trabzon      445         152     293             339     106                     339     106

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, total statistic is unweighted counts. You need specify weighted counts:

```
df %>% 
    tab_cells(F1) %>%
    tab_cols(tepe_kolonlari) %>% 
    tab_weight(sys_RespNum) %>% 
    # 'w_cases' - weighted cases
    tab_stat_cases(total_label = "Sum", total_row_position = "above", total_statistic = "w_cases") %>% 
    tab_pivot() %>% 
    # 'if_na' to show zeroes instead of blanks
    if_na(0)
```